# ubuntu 14 how to reset the default terminal to gnome?

Tags: gnome-terminal

i accidentally changed my default terminal.Now it is xterm.how can i change back to gnome-terminal. i tried
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec gnome-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Go to "system settings" - "details". There should be an option for default applications. Is terminal in there ?

Comment: nope. There's no terminal there.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator

Comment: If you type that command in a terminal you should be presented with a list of installed terminal emulators. Choose one by entering the number and pressing enter. Does that work ?